# ASP.NET MVC reusing Action with different Prefix?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, bind, modelbinders

I have this Action:

```
public ActionResult AddCategory(Category newCategory)
{
    ...//newCategory.Name is filled up
    return new Json(true);
}
```

And a view that post at this Action:

```
@using(Html.BeginForm)
{
@Html.TextBoxFor(Model.Name)
.....
}
```

Now I want to reuse this Action, but in another page.
But in this new View, I already have a Html.TextBox("name") at another . Its a kind of DashBoard.

This new View, have a property NewCategory inside the Model:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public Category NewCategory{get;set;}
}
```

If I do this:

```
@using(Ajax.BeginForm)
{
    @Html.TextBoxFor(Model.NewCategory.Name)
    .....
}
```

Wont work, because my action dont expect any Prefix, in this case NewCategory.

Of course, I can manually call the Action, but doing this I lost built-in validation(I am using DataAnnotation with Unobtrusive validation).

Its a scenario that I fall from time to time

The best choice that I have now is duplicate the Action:

```
public ActionResult AddCategory([Bind(Prefix="NewCategory")]Category category)
{
    ...
    return new Json(true);
}
```

Comment: is your problem that you want mvc built in validation to work in partial views

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to create another method with the "same" assignature:

```
[ActionName("AddCategory")]
public ActionResult AddCategory2([Bind(Prefix="NewCategory2")]Category category)
{
    ...
    return new Json(true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Call Html.RenderAction to reuse action result in other views, and pass name parameter to it for your model, for example:

Use Html.RenderAction("AddCategory", new {name = Model.CategoryName})

Comment: when he has NewCategory in his model why should he execute the action result again. isn't it appropriate to just call RenderPartial and pass Model.NewCategory as model

Comment: @Muhammad if his view for category don't require any special data (that passed through ViewBag/ViewData/TempData from action) except model - using RenderPartial is correct variant. I'm sorry for downvote, edit post please.

Comment: What I want to do is something like this that your said, but I dont want to Render the Action, I want to call this Action via request, just to save the category. AddCategory return a Json(true)

Comment: @Fujiy it is hard to talk about your task, because i dont know: 1. is there a form in you CategoryView 2. if there a from in other view (at that you want to reuse CategoryiIew) or it is simply displaying view 3. What kind of validation you use: by attributes of using other way. Please update question with this details to explain, what you really want. Try to describe scenarios.

Answer (score -1):

what i understand from your question is that you are in some View X and you want to render AddCategory View inside this view and Model of View X contains NewCategory which is of type Category and accepted by AddCategory View as model. if so you just have to call render partial in your View X

```
<%Html.RenderPartial("AddCategory", Model.NewCategory);%>
```